# Ошибка запуска mariadb на локальном сервере laragon (apache)

Tags: mysql, apache, mariadb

При загрузке `Apache` на локальном сервере `Laragon` получаю ошибку запуска бд `mariadb`.

Вот лог, помогите разобраться
**mysqld.log**

```
[Note] InnoDB: 5.7.14 started; log sequence number 4762627838
[Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Laragon\data\ib_buffer_pool
[Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
[Note] Starting crash recovery...
[Note] Crash recovery finished.
[Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
[Note] C:\Laragon\bin\mysql\mariadb-10.2.3-win32\bin\mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '10.2.3-MariaDB-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
[Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
[Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[ERROR] InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported. The redo log was created with MariaDB 10.2.3.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
[Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
[ERROR] Aborting
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
[Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
[Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[ERROR] InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported. The redo log was created with MariaDB 10.2.3.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
[Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
[ERROR] Aborting
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запускайте MariaDB отдельно в режиме восстановления и лечите.

Comment: @Akina можете пояснить подробнее?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-troubleshooting/ - изучите абсолютно всё в разделе. Потом - делайте. PS. Файловый бэкап при остановленном сервере - настоятельно рекомендуется.